# Optimized Alternative of CURSOR

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-cursor

I have the following SQL query that uses **CURSOR** to iterate over each row of the INNER JOIN result. This is not performing well for large sets of data. I need to optimize the query. I tried to find a solution **without using the CURSOR**. But got no solution.

### What is my target?

The idea is to insert at least 2 data for each row of the inner join result. And may insert an extra 3rd row based on a condition.

So, let's say, we have an InnerJoin result table like below

##### InnerJoin Table

| PID | E.CS | E.CE | W.CS | W.CE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 12 | 14 |
| 2 | 3 | 18 | 9 | 9 |

And, for each row of the InnerJoin table, we want to insert rows into another table based on the following rule. Here, 2 rows are surely inserted according to Rule#1 and Rule#2. For Rule#3, a third row may or may not be inserted into the RESULT table.

##### RULES

- (CS, CE) = (E.CS, E.CE)
- (CS, CE) = (Max(E.CS, W.CS), Max(E.CE, W.CE))
- (CS, CE) = IF(W.CS > E.CE) Then (W.CS, W.CE) Else No Entry

So, here is what the result table would look like,

##### Result Table @RETTB

| PID | CS | CE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 12 | 14 |
| 1 | 12 | 14 |
| 2 | 3 | 18 |
| 3 | 9 | 18 |

I have done this with CURSOR by iterating over the InnerJoin table and for each iteration, I insert rows to the result table based on the RULES.

Here is the SQL code,

```
DECLARE 
    @W_CS NUMERIC,
    @W_CE NUMERIC,

    @E_CS NUMERIC,
    @E_CE NUMERIC,

    @CS_1 NUMERIC,
    @CE_1 NUMERIC,

    @CS_2 NUMERIC,
    @CE_2 NUMERIC,

    @maxLoopCount NUMERIC = 5000
-- The CURSOR loop is currently running for a maximum of 5000 times. 
-- This means, that whatever the volume of the InnerJoin table is, the CURSOR will iterate at max 5k times.

DECLARE Cursor_1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT  E.PID,
        E.EDATE,
        E.DAY,
        E.OpID,
        E.CS, 
        E.CE,
        W.CS, 
        W.CE,   
FROM    @Cat E
INNER JOIN @Weekly W
        ON  E.PID = W.PID
        AND E.EDATE = W.EDate
        AND E.DAY = W.DAY   
        AND E.OpID = W.OpID

OPEN    Cursor_1;

---- Perform the first fetch.  
FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_1    INTO 
        @E_CS,
        @E_CE,
        @W_CS,
        @W_CE;  

DECLARE @insertRowCount INT = 0


WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0  AND @maxLoopCount > 0)
BEGIN           
    -- control the loop to prevent deathlock
    Set @maxLoopCount = @maxLoopCount - 1


    SET         @insertRowCount = 0

    INSERT INTO @RETTB  
    SELECT      @E_CS,  @E_CE



    IF (@W_CS < @E_CE)                                      
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @insertRowCount = 2
                ,@CS_1  = @mW_StartCount
                ,@CE_1  = @mE_StartCount
                ,@CS_2  = @mE_EndCount
                ,@CE_2  = @mW_EndCount
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @insertRowCount = 1
                ,@CS_1    = GREATEST(E_CS, W_CS) 
                ,@CE_1  =  GREATEST(E_CE, W_CE)
    END 

    IF @insertRowCount >= 1
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RETTB
        SELECT @CS_1, @CE_1
    END

    IF @insertRowCount = 2
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RETTB
        SELECT      @CS_2, @CE_2
    END

    ---- Perform the next fetch.  
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_1    INTO 
        @E_CS,
        @E_CE,
        @W_CS,
        @W_CE;  

END

CLOSE   Cursor_1;
DEALLOCATE Cursor_1;
```

### What problem am I facing?

This approach is very slow. I need to do it with a set-based approach. But cannot figure it out.

Comment: If you need.to loop up to 5,000 times something has gone *very* wrong in your design; that will be **terrible** for performance. Considering we have no context on what the loop is, then we have no idea how we could emulate that

Comment: It would help if you explain why you need to limit processing to 5000 source rows per execution. Is this just intended to limit the number of rows actively locked at any given moment? How strict is the count? Would it be sufficient to process the TOP (N) ordered PID values per cycle? I have seen code to process rows in batches before, but all contain logic to track work completed so that the next execution can pick up where the prior execution left off. Your logic doesn't show a processing order or restart point.  There should be examples out there for processing (or deleting) rows in batches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for can likely be formed using a `CROSS APPLY` that generates the values you need to insert, derived from the preceding `FROM` clause content.

Typically, the `CROSS APPLY` would contain a `VALUE` tuples collection or a sequence of `SELECT`s merged with a `UNION ALL`. The SELECT/UNION approach allows you to also apply `WHERE` conditions.

Something like:

```
INSERT Target
SELECT C.*
FROM E
JOIN W ON ...
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT E.CS, E.CE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT GREATEST(E.CS, W.CS) AS CS, GREATEST(E.CE, W.CE) AS CE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT W.CS, W.CE WHERE W.CS > E.CE
) C
```

You may need to tweak the `CROSS APPLY` to match your original logic, but the important point of this answer is the technique.

The `GREATEST()` function is available in SQL Server 2022 and later. For earlier versions you can use a `CASE` expression of `IIF()` function like `CASE WHEN E.CS > W.CS THEN E.CS ELSE W.CS END` OR `IIF(E.CS > W.CS, E.CS, W.CS)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am starting to test it and will let know here. One piece of information I mistakenly deleted while editing my post. That is the CURSOR loop is currently running for a maximum of 5k times. This means, that whatever the volume of the InnerJoint table is, the CURSOR will iterate at max 5k times. 
So, how to accommodate that to your solution?

Comment: I would advise you to repost your original code together with a clear explanation of it's intent and function. It is not that we don't want code - we don't want complex code with little or no explanation to help us understand what you have.  Also, please replace your images with text and tables - both sample data and your rule set. Someone may be able to answer your question after you have made these updates.

Comment: It would be very complex to demonstrate the logic that you asked for. Rather I will take care of the max iteration part myself. I am accepting this answer. Thanks.